# ActionEvent "Cannot Find Symbol"

Tags: java, swing, error-handling, actionlistener, actionevent

I am making a program to wrap text, by words or by characters, depending on user input. I have everything working, except for my ActionEvent that's giving me a "Cannot Find Symbol" error. I'm sure it's something small that I've missed, but I can't seem to find it:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class JTextWrap extends JFrame
{
   JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
   TitledBorder tb;
   JRadioButton jrb = new JRadioButton();
   JRadioButton jrb2 = new JRadioButton();
   ButtonGroup btg = new ButtonGroup();
   JCheckBox jdb = new JCheckBox();

   public JTextWrap()
   {
      tb = new TitledBorder("");
      setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
      jta.setText("jTextArea1");
      panel.setBorder(tb);
      tb.setTitle("Wrap Options");
      jrb.setText("Wrap Words");
      jrb.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  JTextWrap.jrb_actionPerformed(e);
               }
            });
      jrb2.setText("Wrap Characters");
      jrb2.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  JTextWrap.jrb2_actionPerformed(e);
               }
            });
      jdb.setText("Wrap");
      jdb.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  JTextWrap.jdb_actionPerformed(e);
               }
            });
      add(scroll, "Center");
      scroll.getViewport().add(jta, null);
      add(panel, "South");
      panel.add(jdb, null);
      panel.add(jrb, null);
      panel.add(jrb2, null);

      btg.add(jrb);
      btg.add(jrb2);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JTextWrap frame = new JTextWrap();
      frame.setTitle("JTextWrap");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
      frame.setSize(400, 300);
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   void jdb_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      jta.setLineWrap(jdb.isSelected());

      if (jdb.isSelected()) {
         jrb.setEnabled(true);
         jrb2.setEnabled(true);
      }
      else {
         jrb.setEnabled(false);
         jrb2.setEnabled(false);
      }
   }

   void jrb_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      jta.setWrapStyleWord(jrb.isSelected());
      jta.revalidate();
   }

   void jrb2_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      jta.setWrapStyleWord(!jrb2.isSelected());
      jta.revalidate();
   }
}
```

Comment: Please consider using an IDE which not only tells you these things, will do them for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ActionEvent` class is in `java.awt.event` package and you have not imported this package.

Comment: That's why as @Brain said you should use an IDE which will do this boilerplate stuff for you.